# How to make Tensorflow Lite model run faster on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I was trying to run this official [Tensorflow Lite repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/super_resolution/android) (`ESRGAN` super resolution model) on Android using Android Studio. I imported the project and it runs smoothly. The repo is a bit old and uses Android NDK to run the TFLite model. When running it, it takes around 250ms (on GPU) to run the model (apply the model on a 50x50 image). But I noticed this [AI Benchmark app](https://ai-benchmark.com/tests.html) also uses the same model to run tests (look at their description of tests, using `ESRGAN`), and it takes around 100ms to run the same model.

What optimizations can be made to make this [Tensorflow Lite repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/super_resolution/android) implementation faster (given it is a bit obsolete)? Why the AI Benchmark implementation is achieving better performance?